# Collapse detail view controller on iPad 12.9'' split screen

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am building a History section for my app which uses SplitViewController to display a calendar as Master and stats for certain day as Detail. Everything works great except for one annoying issue: on the big 12.9'' iPad screen, when in landscape mode and split in half, the width of the frame is of wR size class which causes the SplitViewController to display both Master and Detail, with latter squeezed and pretty much unusable:

[image: landscape half split]

On the other hand, when in portrait mode and 2/3 split screen - although according to Xcode it's also a wR class - my calendar Master takes up the whole frame, with Detail collapsed:

[image]

I would rather prefer this layout in first case as well, but struggle to find a way of force-collapsing the Detail. I tried setting `maximumPrimaryColumnWidth` to the needed size of 678 pt and more, but it had no effect.

Can somebody please suggest an elegant and practical solution to this?

Comment: I've recently developed a library and published on gitHub for IOS devices both iPhone and iPad. It's act like an UISplitViewController but there are more customization option that you can use. https://github.com/ytur/USController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, make a parent view controller of the split view controller and use `setOverrideTraitCollection(_:forChild:)` with compact to make the split collapse when the screen width is a certain size.

Here is the relevant example from Apple's Adaptive Photos sample:

https://github.com/ios8/AdaptivePhotosAnAdaptiveApplication/blob/master/AdaptivePhotos/AAPLTraitOverrideViewController.m

And here is the video of the WWDC 2014 session explaining it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMGnZ5iTmuI

Comment: Overriding traitCollection is a workable solution, just seems a bit heavyweight - I was hoping that UISplitViewController would have some built-in techniques for manual collapsing in various situations.

Comment: Overriding traits isn't heavy weight and it's the standard way. You could try the new iOS 14 colum-base split view controller and see if it works better in 50:50 multitask split on 12.9" iPad Pro.